# Last tick label does not appear in D3 Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, linechart

I'm trying to write a generic multiline chart function based on Mike Bostock's example (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).
I'm facing an issue wherein, the last tick label on my Monthly graph x-axis does not show up. The last tick appears fine on the Weekly graph x-axis.

JS Fiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Jag/11879/

I'm suspecting the issue here could be due to the range specified for the x-axis which for some reason ignores the last value. But I'm not exactly sure what is going on here. Could anyone help me debug ?

Here is my code:

```js
  function renderMultiLineChart(datafile, chartDiv, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, graphCadence){

var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 80, left: 60},
    width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y");

var x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

//var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d){ return d.x;});

switch(graphCadence) {
    case "Daily":
        var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d"))
        break;
    case "Weekly":
        var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeSaturday.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d"))
        break;
    case "Monthly":
        //var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))    
        var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%m/%d"))
        break;
}

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); })

var div = d3.select(chartDiv).append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//https://pharos-rest-service-iad.iad.proxy.amazon.com/s3/tool.csv
d3.csv(datafile, function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    //console.log(d);
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });

  var datapoints = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, count: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  console.log(data);

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(datapoints, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.count; }); }),
    d3.max(datapoints, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.count; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top + 30) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(xAxisLabel);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("fill", "black")    // set the line colour
      .text(yAxisLabel);

  var datapoint = svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
      .data(datapoints)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "datapoint");

  datapoint.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
      
  j = -1;
  datapoint.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d){return d.values})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         div.transition()
           .duration(200)
           .style("opacity", 1);
         div.html("<b>"+d.count+"</b>")
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
         })
       .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         div.transition()
           .duration(500)
           .style("opacity", 0);
         })
    .style("fill", function(d,i) { if (i == 0) { j++ }; return color(datapoints[j].name); });

var legendRectSize = 8;
var legendSpacing = 80;

var legendHolder = svg.append('g')
  // translate the holder to the right side of the graph
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + (100+margin.left+margin.right) + ","+(height+margin.bottom-20)+")")

var legend = legendHolder.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
             if (i === 0) {
                dataL = legendRectSize + legendSpacing
                return "translate(0,0)"
            } else { 
             var newdataL = dataL
             dataL +=  legendRectSize + legendSpacing
             return "translate(" + (newdataL) + ",0)"
            }
        });

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('width', legendRectSize)
  .attr('height', legendRectSize)
  .style('fill', color)
  .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + 5)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize)
  .text(function(d) { return d; });


});
}

renderMultiLineChart("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/techyogii/323024b01c1eb4d0c07637e183e1e6d7/raw/422ed207cc2c38426fa726795ecd963f153135dd/app_usage","div#multiChartMonthly","Snapshot Date","Metric Count","Monthly")

renderMultiLineChart("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/techyogii/8ed38bdb3b8e44194ee8570ef9cc5b75/raw/d0c85aaf9eaa7e8819fd6e6e210885b0cfa6f47d/app_usage_weekly","div#multiChartWeekly","Snapshot Date","Metric Count","Weekly")
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  /*display: none;*/
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  /*width: 60px;
  height: 28px;*/
  padding: 4px;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


  .legend {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  rect {
    stroke-width: 2;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiChartWeekly">
<div id="multiChartMonthly">
```

Thanks,
Yogesh

Comment: Add a buffer on the other end: https://jsfiddle.net/qmL8sdka/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem lies in a misalignment between how `d3.timeMonth` works and how your data is formatted. You see that `d3.timeMonth` is labeling the first of every month, whereas the data is grouped on the last day of every month. So when you call `x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));`, the last data point's date is less than the next label would have been.

One potential solution is to change your parse function to bump all your month dates forward by one day to make them line up with the first of the month. See below.

To remove any dates that end mid-month, you can filter the data set after parsing dates to clean it up.

```js
function renderMultiLineChart(datafile, chartDiv, xAxisLabel, yAxisLabel, graphCadence){


var margin = {top: 20, right: 60, bottom: 80, left: 60},
    width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = function(dateString){
  if(graphCadence == "Monthly"){
    var date = new Date(dateString);
    date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
    return date;
  }
  return d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%y")(dateString);
}

var x = d3.scaleUtc()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

//var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickFormat(function(d){ return d.x;});

switch(graphCadence) {
    case "Daily":
        var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d"))
        break;
    case "Weekly":
        var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeSaturday.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d"))
        break;
    case "Monthly":
        //var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeDay.every(1))    
        var xAxis  = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1)).tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%m/%d"))
        break;
}

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.count); })

var div = d3.select(chartDiv).append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select(chartDiv).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//https://pharos-rest-service-iad.iad.proxy.amazon.com/s3/tool.csv
d3.csv(datafile, function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "date"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
  });
  if(graphCadence == "Monthly"){
    data = data.filter(function(d){
      return d.date.getDate() == 1
    });
  }

  var datapoints = color.domain().map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {date: d.date, count: +d[name]};
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  
  y.domain([
    d3.min(datapoints, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.count; }); }),
    d3.max(datapoints, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.count; }); })
  ]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")             
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," + 
                           (height + margin.top + 30) + ")")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(xAxisLabel);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .style("fill", "black")    // set the line colour
      .text(yAxisLabel);

  var datapoint = svg.selectAll(".datapoint")
      .data(datapoints)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "datapoint");

  datapoint.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
      
  j = -1;
  datapoint.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(d){return d.values})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 3)
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.count); })
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         div.transition()
           .duration(200)
           .style("opacity", 1);
         div.html("<b>"+d.count+"</b>")
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
         })
       .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         div.transition()
           .duration(500)
           .style("opacity", 0);
         })
    .style("fill", function(d,i) { if (i == 0) { j++ }; return color(datapoints[j].name); });

var legendRectSize = 8;
var legendSpacing = 80;

var legendHolder = svg.append('g')
  // translate the holder to the right side of the graph
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + (100+margin.left+margin.right) + ","+(height+margin.bottom-20)+")")

var legend = legendHolder.selectAll('.legend')
  .data(color.domain())
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'legend')
  .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
             if (i === 0) {
                dataL = legendRectSize + legendSpacing
                return "translate(0,0)"
            } else { 
             var newdataL = dataL
             dataL +=  legendRectSize + legendSpacing
             return "translate(" + (newdataL) + ",0)"
            }
        });

legend.append('rect')
  .attr('width', legendRectSize)
  .attr('height', legendRectSize)
  .style('fill', color)
  .style('stroke', color);

legend.append('text')
  .attr('x', legendRectSize + 5)
  .attr('y', legendRectSize)
  .text(function(d) { return d; });


});
}

renderMultiLineChart("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JstnPwll/5a24137a36c9246cf065c58d7f5bb5a5/raw/ff986ee88338e99d10ab93035ffacd3ffe92fd4e/gistfile1.txt","div#multiChartMonthly","Snapshot Date","Metric Count","Monthly")

renderMultiLineChart("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/techyogii/8ed38bdb3b8e44194ee8570ef9cc5b75/raw/d0c85aaf9eaa7e8819fd6e6e210885b0cfa6f47d/app_usage_weekly","div#multiChartWeekly","Snapshot Date","Metric Count","Weekly")
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  /*display: none;*/
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  /*width: 60px;
  height: 28px;*/
  padding: 4px;
  font: 14px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


  .legend {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  rect {
    stroke-width: 2;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div id="multiChartWeekly">
<div id="multiChartMonthly">
```

Comment: Just one more thing, Is there a way I can hide the last point on the graph if the tick is not available for the last day of the month ? With the above mentioned solution, the graph would look incomplete if there is a row with a date that is not the last day of the month.

Comment: Is there any other way to fix it? instead of "ticks(d3.timeMonth.every(1))" changes. We can't predict the range of data.